# XML alternative for @Repository for translation native exceptions to DataAccessException

Tags: spring, exception

I'am trying to configure spring with XML syntax only and come into a problem with native resource exceptions translation to `DataAccessException`. According to documentation I always need to put `@Repository` on repository bean and declare `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` bean. I think that here should be the way to define some sort of filter using AOP which will perform exceptions translation but can't find anything like this in docs. The idea is to introduce convention, for example 'for everything what ends with Dao apply native exceptions translation'. Any ideas?

Comment: apply '@Repository' annotation to dao classes and not to service layer beans. Use '@Service' for service layer beans

Comment: I'd like to achieve the same WITHOUT using any annotations, only with XML configuration. Annotations works fine, I just want to understand an alternative, or be sure that there are no such. In this case Springs team claimings that XML is supported the same way as anntations would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Repository annotaion spring xml config looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
...
        <bean id="translationInterceptor" class="org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor" />

        <aop:config>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="translationInterceptor" pointcut="within(org.example.spring.dao..*Dao)" />
        </aop:config>
...
    </beans>
```

Pointcut "within(org.example.spring.dao..*Dao)" applies interceptor to methods in classes located in package org.example.spring.dao and its subpackages ends with "Dao" suffix